# Android Media Player with seekbar always update and reset

Tags: android, media-player, seekbar

everybody.

First of all, I'm a newbie. I created an activity to play a specific mp3 from raw folder. It works fine and playing it well. I implemented the Media Player as you will see in my code below. But the problem is when I change the orientation of my smartphone , the player continues playing the sound, but a new activity is opened/ updated with the same elements reseted and if I click on PLAY button, the mp3 starts playing, but the old activity stills running on back,  playing the mp3.... so, there are 2 same songs playing now...

I don't want to update the activity or open a new one. I just want to continue playing the song where it was playing before I change the smartphone orientation.

Here is my code:

MP3PlayerActivity.java (main)

```
public class Mp3PlayerActivity extends Activity implements OnPreparedListener {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
private Button btnPlay;
private Button btnPause;
private int current = 0;
private boolean   running = true;
private int duration = 0;
private MediaPlayer mPlayer;
private SeekBar mSeekBarPlayer;
private TextView mMediaTime;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);






    mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.goodthings);
    btnPlay = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btnPause = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    mMediaTime = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.mediaTime);
    mSeekBarPlayer = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);
    mPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);

    mSeekBarPlayer.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {}
        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {}
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
            if(fromUser){
                mPlayer.seekTo(progress);
                updateTime();
            }
        }
    });



    btnPlay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try {
                mPlayer.prepare();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            mPlayer.start();
            mSeekBarPlayer.postDelayed(onEverySecond, 1000);
        }

        public void onCompletion( MediaPlayer mPlayer)
        {
            mPlayer.release();

        }
    });


    btnPause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            mPlayer.pause();
        }
        public void onCompletion( MediaPlayer mPlayer)
        {
            mPlayer.release();

        }
    });
}

private Runnable onEverySecond = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run(){
        if(true == running){
            if(mSeekBarPlayer != null) {
                mSeekBarPlayer.setProgress(mPlayer.getCurrentPosition());
            }

            if(mPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                mSeekBarPlayer.postDelayed(onEverySecond, 1000);
                updateTime();
            }
        }
    }
};

private void updateTime(){
    do {
        current = mPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
        System.out.println("duration - " + duration + " current- "
                + current);
        int dSeconds = (int) (duration / 1000) % 60 ;
        int dMinutes = (int) ((duration / (1000*60)) % 60);
        int dHours   = (int) ((duration / (1000*60*60)) % 24);

        int cSeconds = (int) (current / 1000) % 60 ;
        int cMinutes = (int) ((current / (1000*60)) % 60);
        int cHours   = (int) ((current / (1000*60*60)) % 24);

        if(dHours == 0){
            mMediaTime.setText(String.format("%02d:%02d / %02d:%02d", cMinutes, cSeconds, dMinutes, dSeconds));
        }else{
            mMediaTime.setText(String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d / %02d:%02d:%02d", cHours, cMinutes, cSeconds, dHours, dMinutes, dSeconds));
        }

        try{
            Log.d("Value: ", String.valueOf((int) (current * 100 / duration)));
            if(mSeekBarPlayer.getProgress() >= 100){
                break;
            }
        }catch (Exception e) {}
    }while (mSeekBarPlayer.getProgress() <= 100);
}

@Override
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    duration = mPlayer.getDuration();
    mSeekBarPlayer.setMax(duration);
    mSeekBarPlayer.postDelayed(onEverySecond, 1000);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you rotate your device, `onCreate()` is called again, so all the stuff you do in `onCreate()` is done all over again - which means recreating your `MediaPlayer` and re-setting all of the variables.

What you need to do is only create those things if this is the first time onCreate() is being called.

Have a look here for more info on that.:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html